# How do I take items that are generated in a loop and place them on page in flexbox?

Tags: html, css, loops, flexbox, grid

I have a page that displays multiple pets that are for sale. They are placed onto the page using a loop after a form is filled out. Right now, when I try to place the items into a grid and have them appear as 3 items per row it doesn't work, instead they are all in one column. How do I get items from a loop to display in a grid?

```
<% posts.forEach(function(post) { %>

<div class="flex-container">
    <div class="row justify-content-around">
        <div class="col-sm">
                <h1><%=post.name %></h1>
                <div><%=post.fee %></div>
                <div><%=post.description %></div>
                <div><%= post.location%></div>  
                <div><a href="/gallery/pet/<%=post.id %>">View More</a></div>
                <% }) %>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your css classes are most likely messing things up. I've tidied up the structure of the HTML and used flexbox to align the `col-auto` classes.

Try this:

HTML:

```
 <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
           // for each in items do |item|
            <div class="col-auto">
                <h1>{item.name}</h1>
                <span>£ {item.price}</span>
                <span>{item.description}<span>
                <span>{item.location}<span>  
                <div>
                    <a href="#0">View More</a>
                </div>
            </div>
           // end loop
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.col-auto{
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    width: 33%;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.row{
    display: flex;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100vw;
    flex-direction: row;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. Where should my loop begin in my code? The page needs to display images as they are entered by users and automatically place them in the next open spot of the flexbox.

Comment: You'll need to create a `col-auto` for every entry inside your loop since they're per item, so make that your first dynamic div, then inside there, output your data like name, location etc. I've updated my answer as a demonstration. If you feel my answer helped, please mark it as the accepted answer so others can see it. Cheers!